# PNG image with transparency on SWT

Tags: java, png, swt, transparency

I've got a Composite and would like to use a png file as background image. I can do that, the problem is when the image uses transparency it doesn't work and shows a white colour instead. Any thoughts on how to get this to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Does this article help?

[Taking a look at SWT Images](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-images/graphics-resources.html#Transparency)

It talks about drawing an image (albeit a GIF) to a `Canvas` with transparency (`Canvas` extends `Composite`).

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED! I've solved exactly this problem - displaying PNG files that contain transparent areas. I could not get it to work with Labels (in fact the [article quoted](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-images/graphics-resources.html#Transparency) states "Label does not support native transparency") so I put the image directly into a canvas instead. The other key to success is to use the Image constructor that includes a 3rd parameter, which is the transparency mask. An extra step I did is to call setRegion, which means that mouse events (such as mouse clicks) only fire when they occur over visible pixels.

```
ImageData id = new ImageData("basket.png");
Image image = new Image (display, id, id); //3rd parameter is transparency mask
Canvas c = new Canvas (shell, SWT.TRANSPARENT);
c.addPaintListener(
    new PaintListener(){
        public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) 
        {
            e.gc.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        }
    }
);

//the image has been created, with transparent regions. Now set the active region
//so that mouse click (enter, exit etc) events only fire when they occur over
//visible pixels. If you're not worried about this ignore the code that follows
Region region = new Region();
Rectangle pixel = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1);
for (int y = 0; y < id.height; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < id.width; x++)
    {
        if (id.getAlpha(x,y) > 0)
        {
            pixel.x = id.x + x;
            pixel.y = id.y + y;
            region.add(pixel);
        }
    }
}
c.setRegion(region);
```